# available to / for groups?

Tags: prepositions

In some of the previous posts, I read we should say "something is available TO someone" (when talking about people). Yet, I have just come across this statement: "Special rates are available for school groups" (when talking about admission to galleries etc.) and now I am confused. Any explanation? Should we used to or for?

Comment: Both I guess. I think that also happens in other verbs like "it is for/to you", correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score -1):

There is no specific rule for this.  http://www.indianrail.gov.in/reservation_Rules.html - 'IMPORTANT - FOR SENIOR CITIZENS : From 1st September 2001 onwards, concession to senior citizens'.  We see usage for and to for the same 'group'.  So  "Special rates are available for school groups" or  "Special rates are available to school groups" mean the same.

Comment: Certain prepositions occur with certain adjectives. Is 'available' even mentioned here?

Comment: http://taxguru.in/income-tax/what-are-the-tax-benefits-available-to-senior-citizens.html - 'Tax Benefits Available to Senior Citizens' and 'There are not many income tax exemptions available for senior citizens'.  Both 'available to' and 'available for' are present.  Is 'available' the issue here or is it to/for? :o

Comment: I'll take that as a 'no' – I certainly couldn't find a relevant quote there. At the [British Council Grammar Site](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/adjectives-prepositions) is found: 'Some adjectives go with certain prepositions. There is no real pattern – you need to learn them as you meet them.' While I'd say that the choice of preposition following a particular adjective is usually far more predictable than this, individual pairings always need to be checked; it's not wise to infer them. From logic or from 'nearby examples'.